# How to make table row selectable in ReactJS (No React Table)

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

What I tried to achieve is to make the table row clickable with input element so it will select the entire row. Only the problem is how can I add something like a border when the user checks the input field.

```js
        <tbody>
          {allHotels.map((p: any, index: number) => (
            <TableRow key={p.id} selectRow={true}>
              {console.log(p.checked)}
              <td><input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={p.checked} onClick={() => toggleCheckbox(index)} /></td>
              <td>{p.name}</td>
              <td>{p.address}</td>
              <td>{p.rating}</td>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `toggleCheckbox` function should update the state value representing the checked/unchecked row state.

Given that the `selectRow` prop on the `TableRow` component represents the row state, the code could look something like below:

```js
function Hotels() {
  const [allHotels, setAllHotels] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/api/hotels')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((hotels) => hotels.map((hotel) => ({ ...hotel, selected: false })))
      .then(setAllHotels);
  }, []);

  const toggleCheckbox = (index) => {
    const newHotels = [...allHotels];
    newHotels[index].selected = !newHotels[index].selected;
    setAllHotels(newHotels);
  };

  return (
    <tbody>
      {allHotels.map((hotel, index) => (
        <TableRow key={hotel.id} selectRow={hotel.selected}>
          <td>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              defaultChecked={hotel.checked}
              onClick={() => toggleCheckbox(index)}
            />
          </td>
          <td>{hotel.name}</td>
          <td>{hotel.address}</td>
          <td>{hotel.rating}</td>
        </TableRow>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  );
}
```

Please note that the code needs to be updated according to your needs. But I hope you get the idea.